# updating immutable object array, redux

Tags: react-native, redux

I'm getting error 'Invariant Violation: Tried to get frame for out of range index NaN' due to incorrect assigning/ or empty array being sent from the reducer.
I'm trying to update 3 fields, state.items[index].status, state.items[index].statusUpdatedOn and state.items[index].statusUpdatedBy.

Since its nested, i'm trying update as below in my reducer.
Looks like something wrong with the code, which i'm unable to find out:

```
case ActionTypes.UPDATE_ITEM_STATUS:
  var index = state.items.findIndex((item) => item.id === action.payload.id)
  return { ...state,
    items: {
      ...state.items,
      [index]:{
        ...state.items[index],
        status: action.payload.newStatus,
        statusUpdatedOn: action.payload.statusUpdatedOn,
        statusUpdatedBy: action.payload.statusUpdatedBy
      }
    },
    isLoading: false,
    errMess: null
  }
  break;
```

while my state object is having elements:

```
  items: [],
  errMess: '',
  isLoading: false,
```

Please help me correcting the code

Comment: Is `state.items` an immutable list from immutablejs?
If that's the case and without proper middleware you will need to use toJS/fromJS to interact with it with the native javascript Array API.

Comment: @remix23, state.items is not from immutablejs. afaik, state object in Redux is an immutable one. I've referred to https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuringreducers/immutableupdatepatterns to learn how to update a nested array object

Comment: State in redux is neither guaranted not required to be immutable. It is a good practice thou, from a react perspective, but you have to enforce immutabilty yourself, either by the use of manual destructuration  or by the use of a library like immutablejs.